# how to list how many git public key I have

Tags: macos, git

at some point I created quite a few public key in my system, and I lost track of them. I wonder how to know for sure how many I do I have? and which one is being active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look in ~/.ssh

if you are unsure of how many you need, just copy/rename the .ssh directory and then copy them back in one by one.